# Level 3 data with Stripe Payments

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm working on a SAAS system that allows purchases to be made through a clients own payment gateway.  We have one client that wants to use Stripe as their gateway, however as they are using Corporate Purchase Cards (CPC), it is necessary to pass Level 3 transaction details through.    I've been trying to get details from Stripe on how we ensure that Level 3 data can be passed through successfully, however I'm not really getting anywhere with this in terms of getting any definitive information we can work with.

Stripe say that their system supports level 3 data, we just need to provide the data in the first place, however there is nothing in their documentation about this and the example we have been provided only allows for a single item to be listed - we will need to support a basket of different items.

We are using the Payment Intents process and already support adding in Metadata to the transaction.   We've been told that adding metadata for SKU, Unit of Measure, Unit Price and Extended Price will allow level 3 processing, however this does seem to fall short of the information list on other sources (not to mention does not allow listing multiple items in the order due to the metadata keys needing to be unique)

Baed on that, our Metadata population looks like this (values hard coded to example purposes)

```
Dictionary<string, string> nRetVar = new Dictionary<string, string>();

nRetVar.Add("Customer", "John Smith");
nRetVar.Add("Email", "John.Smith@example.com");
nRetVar.Add("Order Number", "12345");
nRetVar.Add("Order Date", "2020-02-06");
nRetVar.Add("SKU", "ABCD1234");
nRetVar.Add("Unit of Measure", "1 Pack");
nRetVar.Add("Unit Price", "$10.00");
nRetVar.Add("Extended Price", "$15.00");
```

Stripe support never seem to directly answer any of the questions we have been asking about this, so it's proving very hard to get any progress on this - does anyone have enough experience with this to confirm if this metadata is enough to class as level 3, or is there more that we need to be adding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripe supports Level 3 data in their API on both `Charge` and `PaymentIntent`. This feature though is currently "gated" which means you need to get access to the feature on your specific account. It's a bit similar to a long running beta. You should contact their support team again and ask for them to enable Level 3 data on `PaymentIntent` for your account.

The fields they are expecting as specific to that feature. This does not go inside `metadata`. The documentation is also gated which means you can only see it once you get access to the feature, to avoid confusion for other developers who don't have access.

You can see what the shape looks like in stripe-java for example on `Charge` [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stripe/model/Charge.java#L828). The feature is not directly supported on `PaymentIntent` in the library though as this is still private.